# why my integration test trying to connect 172.19.0.2:6565 address and why connection refused

Tags: go, integration-testing, k6, metricbeat, elastic-beats

Hello i'm trying to build an integration test for my project and it's been difficult. I'm trying to do it with using docker. Here is my docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile.

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  k6module:
    build: ./_meta
    ports:
      - 6565
```

```
FROM grafana/k6:latest


COPY ./script.js /home
EXPOSE 6565
CMD ["run", "/home/script.js"]
ENV K6_BROWSER_ENABLED=true

HEALTHCHECK --interval=1s --retries=90 CMD wget --spider --server-response http://localhost:6565 || exit 1
```

in my code i'm trying to collect metrics by using restAPI. When code blocks are like this and i runmy integration test i get that problem:
Expected 0 error, had 1. [error in http fetch: error making http request: Get "http://172.19.0.2:6565/v1/metrics": dial tcp 172.19.0.2:6565: connect: connection refused]

Here is my integration-test:

```
package k6metricset

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/elastic/beats/v7/libbeat/tests/compose"
    mbtest "github.com/elastic/beats/v7/metricbeat/mb/testing"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestFetch(t *testing.T) {
    service := compose.EnsureUp(t, "k6module")

    f := mbtest.NewReportingMetricSetV2Error(t, getConfig(service.Host()))
    events, errs := mbtest.ReportingFetchV2Error(f)
    if len(errs) > 0 {
        t.Fatalf("Expected 0 error, had %d. %v\n", len(errs), errs)
    }
    assert.NotEmpty(t, events)

    t.Logf("%s/%s event: %+v", f.Module().Name(), f.Name(), events[0])
}

func TestData(t *testing.T) {
    service := compose.EnsureUp(t, "k6module")

    f := mbtest.NewReportingMetricSetV2Error(t, getConfig(service.Host()))
    if err := mbtest.WriteEventsReporterV2Error(f, t, ""); err != nil {
        t.Fatal("write", err)
    }
}

func getConfig(host string) map[string]interface{} {
    return map[string]interface{}{
        "module":     "k6module",
        "metricsets": []string{"k6metricset"},
        "hosts":      []string{host},
    }
}
```

First of all i don't understand why the 172.19.0.2:6565 address? How can i change this address. It shouldn't try to connect that address.
And i can't see the metrics via curl or wget. When i change the docker-compose.yml file to this:

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  k6module:
    build: ./_meta
    network_mode: "host"
```

i can see metrics in localhost:6565 address. But my integration-test fails again. And the error is; getting host for k6module: unknown host:port for service.

Please i'm trying to solve this problem for like 2 weeks and i couldn't do it.

I tried to look my container's logs or using inspect command. K6 is running it's okay but the integration test fails everytime.

Comment: yes i know but idk why it's trying to access 172.19.0.1 address. I can't find why it's taking this ip address for collecting metrics. It should look localhost or some kind of address that reaches metrics.